# Filter and select a dataset based on a value in a row

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have looked into dplyr and tidyr and even base R but I cannot seem to figure out how to subset my data based on a row value.

I have tried using dplyr `filter()` and `select()` functions but because `gender`, `language`, and `age` are in the `id` column, I cannot filter by just typing `data %>% filter(gender == 1)`.

I have a list of 50 raters. For the example here I will display 5. I have 183 rows, which include the raters answers to each question and the three last rows have demographic data, such as age, gender and whether someone is a native or non-native speaker. I will illustrate here with 6 rows as an example.

What I am trying to do is find a way to subset my data according to the values in the age, gender, and language values. Let's say I want to select all the ratings for gender 1, or for language 1, or for gender 1 AND language 1.

Thank you.

Code:

```
data <- data.frame("id" = c(901,902,903,"age",
                                        "gender",
                                        "language"), 
                   "rater1" = c(7, 9, 9, 21, 1, 1),
                   "rater2" = c(9, 9, 9, 39, 2, 2),
                   "rater3" = c(9, 9, 9, 38, 2, 1),
                   "rater4" = c(9, 9, 9, 33, 2, 1),
                   "rater5" = c(2, 9, 9, 21, 2, 1))
```

Comment: try `library(tidyverse)`  then filter()

Comment: Look into `dolyr::filter`

Comment: Please show what you have tried and hasn't worked. Otherwise it's hard to know where to target the answer.

Comment: @Gregor I've tried using dplyr, using filter to no avail. I'll update my post.

Comment: What is the meaning of the first 3 ids, 901, 902, 903? Are those something like question ids that the raters respond to?

Comment: @Gregor correct, I have different id numbers for the sentences subjects rated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to filter by gender and the other variables of interest we will need to rearrange the data so that they are columns and not rows within a column.  One way we can do that is to use gather and then spread.  After changing the structure you can utilize dplyr filtering.

```
data <- data %>% 
  gather("Rater",rater1:rater5, value = "Value") %>% 
  spread(id, value = Value) %>% 
  filter(gender == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not sure whether this scales well for your use case but you could do basic indexing:

```
# data
x <- data.frame("id" = c(901,902,903,"age","gender","language"), 
                   "rater1" = c(7, 9, 9, 21, 1, 1),
                   "rater2" = c(9, 9, 9, 39, 2, 2),
                   "rater3" = c(9, 9, 9, 38, 2, 1),
                   "rater4" = c(9, 9, 9, 33, 2, 1),
                   "rater5" = c(2, 9, 9, 21, 2, 1))

# ensure id is character and not factor
x$id <- as.character(x$id)

# select all raters whose gender or language is 1
x[, c(TRUE, x[x$id == "gender", -1] == 1) |
    c(TRUE, x[x$id == "language", -1] == 1) ]
```

The `TRUE` ensures that the id column is kept in any case and the `-1` ensures that the logical vector has the desired length (number of columns).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest working with two data frames, one (I call `demo`) for the demographic information on raters, 1 row per rater, and one (I call ratings) for the ratings each rater gave, 1 row per response:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
demo = tail(data, 3)
ratings = head(data, -3)

demo_cols = demo$id
demo = data.frame(t(demo[-1]))
names(demo) = demo_cols
demo$rater = as.numeric(sub(pattern = "rater", replacement = "", rownames(demo)))
demo
#        age gender language rater
# rater1  21      1        1     1
# rater2  39      2        2     2
# rater3  38      2        1     3
# rater4  33      2        1     4
# rater5  21      2        1     5

ratings = tidyr::pivot_longer(ratings, cols = starts_with("rater"),
                              names_to = "rater", names_prefix = "rater") %>%
  mutate(rater = as.numeric(rater))
ratings
# # A tibble: 15 x 3
#    id    rater value
#    <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 901   1         7
#  2 901   2         9
#  3 901   3         9
#  4 901   4         9
#  5 901   5         2
#  6 902   1         9
#  ...
```

Then, when you want to do something like *"select all the ratings for gender 1, or for language 1, or for gender 1 AND language 1"*, you do a simple `filter` of `demo`, and join to the `ratings` data to get the matching records:

```
demo %>% filter(gender == 1 & language == 1) %>%
  inner_join(ratings)
# Joining, by = "rater"
#   age gender language rater  id value
# 1  21      1        1     1 901     7
# 2  21      1        1     1 902     9
# 3  21      1        1     1 903     9
```

You could also do the complete join
`ratings_with_demo = inner_join(ratings, demo)` and filter that data frame directly. But remember if you do this that each row is a *response*. If you want to do something like count the number of raters by `gender`, the `demo` data frame is a much nicer starting place.

Answer (score 1):

Just turn it on its side. Make sure to turn `id` into row names first, and then remove `id` to prevent type coercion. `t` also returns a matrix, so you'll need to turn the data back into a data frame with `as_tibble` or `as.data.frame`:

```r
library(dplyr)
data <- as_tibble(t(`rownames<-`(data, data$id)[-1]))
```

Now `filter` should do what you expect:

```r
data %>% filter(gender == 1)

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 1 x 6
  `901` `902` `903`   age gender language
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     7     9     9    21      1        1
```